# Do you get passport checked on a round trip to Antarctica from Ushuaia, Argentina?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports, argentina

I'm considering travelling to Antarctica this November, from Argentina.

I have a passport which will hit the six months-remaining window around mid-November.

While I'd enter Argentina before that window, which is no problem, I'm wondering if they'll look at my passport again when the boat returns, which could then be a problem.

Does anyone know if there is immigration control - even though you've not technically been to any other country in the period since you 'left' Argentina?

Comment: I don't know about Argentina specifically, but there is certainly passport control in Christchurch for people returning from the ice. Apparently even the Apollo astronauts even had to have their passports checked upon return (although I'm sure that was largely a formality!).

Comment: Why do you think that your passport needs to be valid for six months when entering Argentina (there seem to be no such requirement) and why do you even assume that there will be no passport control when reentering Argentina the second time (no matter where you actually come from)?

Comment: I assume nothing, that's why I asked the question.  I can guess, but I'd rather have some evidence.

Comment: Isn't it usually 6 months *after you return to your home country*?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Antarctic Peninsula is a part of the sector of Antarctica claimed by Argentina. If you are taking a ship that goes only there (and not to the Falkland Islands, for example), you are technically not leaving Argentina at all.

I went to the Antarctic Peninsula from Ushuaia last November. The crew took my passport before I boarded the ship, and returned it just before we came back to Ushuaia. I don't know what kind of formalities there were before the departure, but at least I didn't get an exit stamp to the passport. When the ship returned to Ushuaia, they just transfered us to our hotels without any formalities.